# How to reconnect an API app on Vimeo

Tags: vimeo

I have an API app on Vimeo that I use to collect data such from my videos such as views and privacy settings. It is listed at https://developer.vimeo.com/apps .

I was looking to include upload access and, in doing so, I clicked the button "Disconnect" on my app at https://vimeo.com/settings/apps. Now the app no longer works and I get `<Response [401]>` (Unauthorized) from Vimeo. I cannot find how to reconnect it on either page, nor did I find any documentation about connecting or disconnecting apps.

How can I connect my Vimeo app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After emails with Vimeo support, the problem was that by disconnecting the app, the personal access token was revoked. To reconnect the app, create a new personal access token at https://developer.vimeo.com/apps:

[image: Vimeo generate access token]

Then the app should become listed at https://vimeo.com/settings/apps. Remember to change the previous token to the new one in your client-side code.